# angular-cli: ng g component generates wrong import path (backslash) in app.module

Tags: angular, angular-cli

To create an component in `angular-cli`, run `ng g component webapi.component` and get all files excepting the line in `app.module.ts`:

```
import { WebapiComponent } from './components\webapi/webapi.component';
```

Any idea whhy the backslash appears after `./components\' ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a current bug that occurs on Windows based operating systems in conjuction with the terminal you're are using. Basically, it's not converting the path delim to unix style forward slashes. I've seen some weirdness with Git Bash and Angular-cli, so to rule out the possibility of your terminal try the same ng generate line in cmd prompt.